# Is there a URI Scheme to prompt the user to save a contact to his smartphone?

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, contacts, uri-scheme

I would like to know that if like "tel:", "mailto:", "sms:", etc.. is there a URI Scheme to prompt the user to save a contact to his smartphone.

For example, the user is browsing on a web page and clicks a button, he is then prompted to save a contact on his phone.

I know there is vCard, but the user has to download it then open it, unlike "tel:" or "mailto:", is there an equivalent of those for saving a contact?

Comment: QR Codes [apparently have this capability](http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/qr-codes-uri-schemes/).

Comment: I know, but if you are browsing with your phone, you cannot scan it.